# Access angular 6 component via URL using ZUUL as proxy

Tags: spring-boot, angular6, angular-routing, netflix-zuul

I have 2 Spring Boot apps, one acts as a data provider and one is just a wrapper for my Angular 6 application to be able to deploy it on server with `java -jar JAR_NAME`.

While working on my Angular app using angular-cli and running it with `ng serve` I can see the first page at `http://localhost:4200` that redirects me to localhost:4200/index. I have another component mapped to /comp and while accessing localhost:4200/comp that new component is displayed on page.

The problem appears when I deploy my app wrapped in the spring jar and try to access the routes from Angular directly. My spring app is served at localhost:8999 and at hitting that I'm redirected to localhost:8999/index and the page loads fine. If clicking on the button that redirects me to the `comp` page, the url is changing to localhost:8999/comp and the resources are served properly. The problem is that if I access localhost:8999/index or localhost:8999/comp I get a 404 error.

Relevant pieces of code:
`From application.yml:`

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    g-api:
      path: /loc/**
      url: http://localhost:8443/api
```

From app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'index', component: FirstComp},
  {path: 'comp', component: SecondComp}}
```

From navbar html:

```
 <li class="n">
        <a class="na"
           [routerLink]="['/comp']" >
          <i class="a"></i>
          <p>comp</p>
        </a>
      </li>
```

As a note, the zuul proxy is working even when deployed with spring so I'm able to retrieve data from the API deployed on different port. But if I refresh or access some Angular component via URL I get a 404.

PS: not a front end developer here.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/notFound").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}


@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                "/notFound"));
    };
}
```

}

From Spring, configure all not founds to go to `/notFound`, then add a `ViewController` that serves a forward to your `index.html`. This is for spring boot 2